# calling function to get JSON response result from another python file

Tags: python, json

I have an example script `get_json.py` like this:

```
import cv2
import os
import json
import requests
import time

vehicle_count = [0]
current_path = os.getcwd()
file = '/dir/image' + str(len(vehicle_count)) + ".png"
path = '/home/username/Documents/path/to/image%s' % file
temp_file = current_path + file
result = []

def send_image(source_image):
    cv2.imread(temp_file)
    # vehicle_count.insert(0, 1)
    with open(path, 'rb') as fp:
        response = requests.post(
            'https://GET_API/',
            files=dict(upload=fp),
            headers={'Authorization': 'Token ' + 'KEYS'})
        result.append(response.json())
        # print(json.dumps(result, indent=2));

        with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile:
            json.dump(result, outfile)
    # os.remove("%s" %temp_file)
    resp_dict = json.loads(json.dumps(result, indent=2))
    if resp_dict[0]['results']:
        num=resp_dict[0]['results'][0]['image']
        # boxs=resp_dict[0]['results'][0]['box']
        # xmins,ymins,ymaxs,xmaxs=boxs['xmin'],boxs['ymin'],boxs['ymax'],boxs['xmax']
        # cv2.rectangle(frame, (xmins, ymins), (xmaxs, ymaxs), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        # font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
        # cv2.putText(frame,num,(xmins, ymins-10), font, 1,(0, 255, 0),2,cv2.LINE_AA)
        # cv2.imshow("detected frame",frame)
        # cv2.waitKey(0)
        # cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        print(f"json result: {num}")
```

and while executing, it will send an image to API and get the output in JSON format. So I want to call `num` result from another python file like `get_num.py`. How to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: You have to use modules and call this method from other file. See https://www.learnpython.org/en/Modules_and_Packages

Comment: if it is in the same directory `from get_num import num` to import the `num()` function from the get_num module

Comment: i got error `NameError: name 'source_image' is not defined` when i try to call function `send_image(source_image)` @ArunM

Comment: `num` is not a function, it's a some result from function `send_image()` @TenaciousB

Comment: If num is a global variable in the other module then it should import it if you remove the parentheses